# Why are directories under /mnt not visible when mounting filesystem with NFS?

Tags: nfs, autofs

I setup an NFS share on my NFS server with `/etc/exports` containing `/ *(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)`
Then I do `exportfs -a` to activate the share and restart the nfs server.

I mount the share with autofs on the client machine with `/etc/auto.nfs` containing `foo   -fstype=nfs4,soft,rw,noatime,allow_other   server.tld:/`

My `auto.master` contains `/mnt/nfs /etc/auto.nfs --timeout=30 --ghost`

I restart autofs (systemctl restart autofs.service)

Then I see all directories from the server. But when I try to navigate to mounted serverdisks under /mnt/mounteddiskonserver I can't see anything anymore. No files, no directories, no write permission through nemo file browser on the client machine.
I can go to /home/user on the server and see and delete all my files on the server that have same permissions as /mnt/mounteddiskonserver/fileshere.

When I setup the NFS server to share /mnt/mounteddiskonserver specifically with with `/etc/exports` containing `/mnt/mounteddiskonserver *(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)` I can see all files and directories under /mnt/mounteddiskonserver and I can read and write.

Comment: `auto.master` - that first path should be `/mnt/nfs` rather than `mnt/nfs`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Your list of export options for the root filesystem does not include `crossmnt`. As a result, you must explicitly export each separate filesystem under the NFS server's `/mnt` if you wish to have them accessible over NFS.

This is actually a good thing, as granting access to `/dev` over NFS is unlikely to achieve anything very useful, and accessing `/proc` or `/sys` over NFS might be confusing or even harmful. (Since devices are accessed by minor & major device numbers, the device nodes on the NFS-mounted `/dev` would still map to the corresponding devices of the *client host*. Any kind of caching would likely give you stale data from a NFS-exported `/proc`.)

You may have your reasons for exporting the root filesystem of your NFS server (which itself would be, in my opinion, a questionable practice), but adding `crossmnt` to its export options would enable you to shoot yourself in the foot with a multi-barrel Gatling gun if anyone with root access makes a mistake in the NFS client system. If you absolutely must, make a separate `/etc/exports` line for `/mnt` and add the `crossmnt` option to that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `crossmnt` was the solution. I do not really need to mount root dir but while playing around with NSF I stumbled upon this behaviour and wondered why it didn't work. I'm satisfied with exporting `/mnt/disk/folder` alone.